# Active filtering datagridview with texbox when datagridview has a checkbox column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filtering

Ιn VB.NET i have a datagridview which has as datasource a datatable.

In order to achieve active filtering, i have a textbox with the follwing code on TextChanged event.

```
Private Sub KryptonTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles KryptonTextBox1.TextChanged, KryptonTextBox5.TextChanged
    DirectCast(KryptonDataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("userid like '%{0}%' or name like '%{0}%'", KryptonTextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

When i decided to use a checkbox type column , i saw that when a user has made some checks and then he filters, the checks are lost beacuse the datatable is reloaded ...

Any ideas ? (except storing the checked values in the database because i have no rights to do this in the specific case)

Comment: Setting a Filter doesn't change the values assigned to Columns. If that happens, then the values you have set are not saved to the data source. -- It looks like the DataSource of your DGV is a DataTable.

Comment: When you say the dataview is reloaded, what exactly do you mean by that?  Are you re-querying the source DB?

Comment: Sorry i misspelled ... the datagridview is connected with Datatable . I Edited the original question. And about re-quering the source db i think that with the method i have used the answer is that the sourcedb is not re-quered

Comment: What is the datatype of the column bound to the checkbox column in the DataTable? If it is other than a boolean, how did you determine checked/unchecked?

Comment: @Mary I dont understand why you are asking about the datatype of the column and what do you mean by boolean as a Datatype of  a column . The datatype of the column is  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Comment: I asked about it because that is the column where you are losing data. Is it a secrete?

Comment: Oops! @Mary , sorry no offence ! My question was about undestanding why you were asking about the data type because i had already mentioned in the question that it is a CheckBox column and as far as i know there is one datatype for checkbox columns. I asked in order to understand if there may other types and maybe your question was the key to the answer.

Comment: No problem, I want to know the datatype of the column in the DataTable and the database. This will tell me if the value of the checkbox is being saved back to the DataTable in a compatible type.

Comment: ok , so the type  is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn